# How to Resolve .Net application with DB2 as Database gives error SQL0433N Value <Lob-value> is too long for VARCHAR (32000)?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, db2

I have a .Net application 4.5  where we are doing bulk loading of data from some table (DB2 V10 is database) based on user defined ID through stored procedure where the UID_Field VARCHAR (32000).
Sometimes , bulk loading of data fail and we get the error as ERROR[2201][IBM][DB2] SQL 0433N Value "" is too long .
The SP used CONCAT function for UID_Field for query results .

My worry is only sometimes we get this error even when there is not much data , i mean the length doesn't exceed 32000 and mostly it works fine. I am trying to understand why this error is coming even though length size is 3000 only .

Is there any way to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Difficult to help without seeing the exact __SQL code__ involved, plus exact version/platform details (v10 is not clear, which platform is it, which version/modification/fixpack is your Db2-server). and show whose odbc driver you are using and the odbc-driver-version.  That information shoud all be in your question, and you should use correct tags to identify the Db2-server platform.